# How do I run FlyWay clean with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I'm using Spring Boot and FlyWay together.  I added the FlyWay dependency to my Gradle build file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1202-jdbc42")
    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}
```

I also added a `db/migrations` folder with an initial migration file.  The migration works as expected.  But now I want to clean by using the `gradle flywayClean` task.  However, when I run this, I get an error saying the task can't be found.  Is there another way I'm supposed to do this with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run `gradle flywayClean`, you have to apply the plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'

See http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/gradle.html

Comment: Updated link: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/getstarted/firststeps/gradle